# What are the pros and cons of typing interface method parameters generic to make the interface more accessible?

Tags: abap

I have an application that creates xml strings from abap structures using many different simple transformations and consequently many different abap structures.

I want to use a more flexible OO approach with an Interface to do this but due to the different structures the method signatures importing parameter is always different.

What are the pros and cons of typing the importing parameter generic instead so I can implement one method from one interface in each class handling the different transformations?

```
INTERFACE if_transformer.
  METHODS transform_xml
    IMPORTING isource_structure TYPE REF TO data
    RETURNING VALUE(rxml_string) TYPE string.
ENDINTERFACE. 

...

CLASS material_transformer definition.
  PUBLIC SECTION.
    INTERFACES if_transformer.
ENDCLASS.

CLASS material_transformer IMPLEMENTATION.
METHOD if_transformer~transform_xml.
  FIELD-SYMBOLS <structure> TYPE concrete_structure.
  ASSIGN isource_structure->* TO <structure>.
  ...
ENDMETHOD.
ENDCLASS.
```

Comment: this type of questions are better suited for [ABAP style guidelines](https://github.com/SAP/styleguides/issues/179), here they most probably will be closed as opinion-based

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The more specific your types, the earlier you notice errors, the easier your interfaces can be understood, and the less overhead you have in validating and casting/converting to the concrete types you want to handle.

For example, consider you type the method `add_number` as `methods add_number importing n type i`. The compiler will then reject the wrong statement `add_number( 'xyz' )` and this class of errors will never make it into executable code. In turn, anybody reading that method's declaration can easily see that the method accepts only integer numbers, not floats, not packeds, and definitely not strings that contain numbers. Within the method, you can probably directly take the input `n` and do something with it, such as `result = sum_so_far + n`, without having to first validate the input or convert it to something else.

In contrast, consider you type the same method `add_number` as `methods add_number importing n type ref to data`. The compiler will gladly accept `add_number( ref #( 'xyz' ) )`, although it is complete nonsense; this class of error will thus only be detected at runtime, with type conversion exceptions that the code around this will have to react to in a meaningful way. People reading the method's declaration have to consult its docu, unit tests, and/or code to find out what kind of input it accepts; there is no way to guess it from the specification alone. Finally, within the method, you will first have to validate and convert the input before you can process it, such as `is_integer( n )`, `cast`, `assign`, and the like; in case the input is unacceptable, you need to find suitable error handling mechanisms, such as throwing nice exceptions.

With softly typed languages like JavaScript, using generic types is the default. However, history shows that people often prefer stronger typing, at least on the server side, leading to follow-up evolutions such as TypeScript or Deno. With strongly-typed languages like ABAP, the rule of thumb is to choose a data type as precise as possible.

Note that there are several levels of relaxation in generic types. For example, you should consider resorting to "partially" generic types like `simple`, which accepts ABAP structures, or `standard table`, which accepts tables, before resorting to the maximum-generic type `data`.

Comment: By the way: When your method `add_number` only does arithmetic, then you might declare its import parameter as the [generic type](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_751_index_htm/7.51/en-US/abenbuilt_in_types_generic.htm) `numeric`, which allows it to accept all numeric types (`i`, `f`, both `decfloat`s and `p` with any length and decimals).

Comment: Thank you for your input Florian and Philipp, the "partially" generic approach seems to be the best solution for my template method.

Answer (score 1):

Excellent answer by Florian. I might add that an approach I've used in similar scenarios is to use a factory class that inspects the input data and instantiates the appropriate class to deal with it.